# Не корректная работа функции с указателями

Tags: c, функции, указатели

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *remove_url_anchor(const char *url_in) {
  char result[strlen(url_in)];
  char *rp;
  unsigned int counter = 0;

  while (*url_in) {
    if (*url_in=='#') break;
    result[counter] = *url_in;
    url_in++;
    counter++;
  }
  rp = result;
  # если вывожу тут выводит правильный результат
  return rp;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char word[11] = "Hello#index";
  char *solution = remove_url_anchor(word);

  printf("%s", solution); #не выводит ничего, должно Hello
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: [strdup()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) поможет вам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы возвращаете из функции указатель на локальную переменную `result`. Память, которую эта переменная занимает, может быть переписана в любой момент после окончания функции.